# How to fill missing terms with a value exactly 24 intervals ago in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a data from the sensors of solar radiation for whole year in hourly resolution. The data for some hours is missing and it needs to be filled with values exactly 24 hours ago. As Solar radiations are almost same next day at the same time.

The sample pic of the data is

[image]

The missing data is as shown below
[image]

The code I learnt for filling suggests something like the following

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.read_excel('ffill_test.xlsx')
df['Solar Power'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace= True)

print(df)
```

How can I get the interval fill with interval of 24 values. The other option I am thinking is to convert it to the list and then use loop to replace it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the DataFrame.shift can help here? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: some problem? Solution does not work?

Comment: Its giving some errors

Comment: It's giving `key error: 'Date'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple dataset:

```
df
      a
0   1.0
1   3.0
2   5.0
3   7.0
4   7.0
5   NaN
6   3.0
7  24.0
```

We would like to fill `np.nan` with a previous value:

```
df.a.fillna(df.a.shift(3))

0     1.0
1     3.0
2     5.0
3     7.0
4     7.0
5     5.0
6     3.0
7    24.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

In your case:

```
df['Solar Power'].fillna(df['Solar Power'].shift(24))
```

Comment: if two values are consectively missing the I have to write this code two times. `-------` For Example, if the sensor missed reading at 8:00 on two consective days the code above will fill the `Nan` at 8:00 on first day but not on the second day. `----------`. What is the solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you need create [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) created by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed values by `24H`:

```
print (df)
        Date     Time  System Power  Solar Power
0   6/15/2016  0:00:00           1.0         10.0
1   6/15/2016  0:00:01           2.0         20.0
2   6/15/2016  0:00:02           3.0         30.0
3   6/15/2016  0:00:03           4.0         40.0
4   6/15/2016  0:00:04           5.0         50.0
5   6/15/2016  0:00:05           6.0         60.0
6   6/15/2016  0:00:06           7.0         70.0
7   6/15/2016  0:00:07           8.0         80.0
8   6/15/2016  0:00:08           9.0         90.0
9   6/15/2016  0:00:09          10.0        100.0
10  6/15/2016  0:00:10          11.0        110.0
11  6/16/2016  0:00:04           NaN          NaN
12  6/16/2016  0:00:06           NaN          NaN

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) +  pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str)) 
cols = ['System Power','Solar Power']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df[cols].shift(24, freq='H'))
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
         Date     Time  System Power  Solar Power
0   6/15/2016  0:00:00           1.0         10.0
1   6/15/2016  0:00:01           2.0         20.0
2   6/15/2016  0:00:02           3.0         30.0
3   6/15/2016  0:00:03           4.0         40.0
4   6/15/2016  0:00:04           5.0         50.0
5   6/15/2016  0:00:05           6.0         60.0
6   6/15/2016  0:00:06           7.0         70.0
7   6/15/2016  0:00:07           8.0         80.0
8   6/15/2016  0:00:08           9.0         90.0
9   6/15/2016  0:00:09          10.0        100.0
10  6/15/2016  0:00:10          11.0        110.0
11  6/16/2016  0:00:04           5.0         50.0
12  6/16/2016  0:00:06           7.0         70.0
```